# How to change timezone by integer value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, timezone-offset

My current `Time` object looks like that:

```
2015-01-10 17:13:00.000000000 +0000
```

While I need it to look like that:

```
2015-01-10 18:13:00.000000000 +0100
```

I'd like to just set a value of timezone offset to receive that, without knowing names of timezones in strings, somethig like:

```
my_date.set_timezone_offset(1)
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to change the Time depending by the given offset, you have to use `new_offset` method which is part of `DateTime` (not sure if this works this `Time` objects, if not you can try to parse it):

```
time = "2015-01-10 17:13:00.000000000 +0000".to_datetime
```

Then use the method:

```
time.new_offset("+10:00")
```

This will return DateTime with provided offset also changed time according to that offset.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.now.change(offset: "+0100")
```

Returns datetime with provided offset

Comment: Strange, it works for DateTime, but for Time it doesn't. Is there some alternative for Time objects too?